# Using Soap Services

Tags: java, android

How to write in Toast or Textview If data is not found from the soap service 
this is my code here.....
   and i taken data in listview using soap services

```
    String strValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value").toString();

    if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

        tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.prasent_report));
        URL = "";
        SOAP_ACTION = "";
        USER_LOGIN_METHOD_NAME = "";


    }else if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

        tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.absent_report));
        URL = "";
        SOAP_ACTION = "";
        USER_LOGIN_METHOD_NAME = "";

    }else if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){

        tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.attendence_report));
        URL = "";
        SOAP_ACTION = "";
        USER_LOGIN_METHOD_NAME = "";
    }
    else    if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: What you want ??? clear first...

Comment: can you plz mention what exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Soap,than i guess you might be using something like this.
Put a try catch block,so if some error occurs you can give some toast message like this.

```
private class LongOperationFetchData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {               
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                try 
                {
                 //Put your code here
                 String strValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value").toString();

                 if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

                 tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.prasent_report));
                 URL = "";
                 SOAP_ACTION = "";
                 USER_LOGIN_METHOD_NAME = "";


                 }else if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

               tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.absent_report));
           URL = "";
          SOAP_ACTION = "";
            USER_LOGIN_METHOD_NAME = "";

          }else if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){

           tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.attendence_report));
             URL = "";
            SOAP_ACTION = "";
          USER_LOGIN_METHOD_NAME = "";
       }
       else    if(strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                         //Toast will occur when data not found.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                            
                        }
                    });


}
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                         //Toast will occur when data not found.
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sorry Server Error Occurred,Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                 
                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```